# Sentencia sql y página amigable para Seo

Tags: php, seo

Tengo el siguiente código que extrae los datos de la tabla idiomas online.

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT id, ingles, precio FROM idiomasonline order by id desc";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
```

Actualmente lo estoy ordenando por **id** de forma descendente, sin embargo le quiero añadir dos filtros, estos son por **precio** de mayor a menor y de menor a mayor.

Mi idea es crear un nuevo fichero por cada sentencia y hacer la llamada desde un `select` de formulario. Hasta ahí todo iría bien. Sin embargo de cara al Seo como afecta? Ya que en mi opinión sería los mismos datos, pero se mostrarían de forma diferente.

Lo que he estado pensando y no se que opinais, sería en los dos archivos nuevos los de mayor a menor y menor a mayor añadirle dentro de `head` la etiqueta `noindex`.

No se que os parece la idea o alguna sugerencia?

Esta parte es importante de cara al Seo para que Google no dectecte contenido duplicado.

Gracias y un saludo.

---

Al final he optado por lo que proponia al principio. He creado el siguiente formulario:

```html
      <form action="" name="seleccionar" method="post">

<select name="seleccionar" value="seleccionar" onchange="document.location.href=this.value">

<option selected disabled>Ordenar precio</option>
<option value="https://www.mipaginawebesta.es/clases-ingles-online/mayor-a-menor.php">Mayor a menor</option>
<option value="https://www.mipaginawebesta.es/clases-ingles-online/menor-a-mayor.php">Menor a mayor</option>

</select>

</form>
```

En la página principal y por otra parte he creado los dos ficheros:
mayor-a-menor.php
menor-a-mayor.php

En mayor-a-menor.php

```html
   <?php 
    $sql = "SELECT id, ingles, precio FROM idiomasonline order by id desc";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
```

En menor-a-mayor.php

```html
  <?php 
    $sql = "SELECT id, ingles, precio FROM idiomasonline order by id asc";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
```

Y en estos dos fichero que he creado dentro de la etiqueta head he agregado:

```html
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

Desde mi humilde opinión creo que no voy a tener problemas con la parte seo en el tema duplicado de contenido, aunque he creado dos nuevos archivos. Por otro lado para más indicaciones a los robots dentro del fichero robots.txt agrego:

```html
Disallow: mayor-a-menor.php
Disallow: menor-a-mayor.php
```

Answer (score 3):

Considera el envío de parámetros para los filtros de precio desde el frontend. Asumiendo que es `HTML` quedaría así por ejemplo:

```
<select name="filtroPrecio">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="asc">Ascendente</option>
    <option value="desc">Descendente</option>
</select>
```

Luego en `PHP` declaras una variable, seteas los parámetros recibidos y agregas esta variable al final del `query`.

```
<?php 
    if ($_POST['filtroPrecio] === '') {
        $filtroPrecio = '';
    } else {
        $filtroPrecio = ', precio '.$_POST['filtroPrecio];
    }
    $sql = "SELECT id, ingles, precio 
            FROM idiomasonline 
            ORDER BY id desc".$filtroPrecio." ";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
```

Con esto te evitas el uso de diferentes archivos para usar una misma función.

Comment: Muchas gracias DjCrazy

Comment: Si la respuesta resolvió tu duda, considera aceptarla con el check que está debajo de los botones para votar. De esta manera servirá como referencia para futuros visitantes y de paso ambos ganamos reputación en el comunidad.